# Database server configuration

Tags: mysql, database, windows, server

I want to create a database server using mysql for my local network application.
Which operating system is best Windows or Linux ?
I don't have much knowlegde about Linux.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely Linux. You should start learning! There's a lot of good guides on how to install a Linux server.

I would recommend Ubuntu for a starter, it's easier in my opinion.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Comment: Of course you are right @numsu.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for an easy to use GUI environment they have a good Windows installation and Mysql Workbench.